# Python Knapsack function, missing argument

Tags: python, function, knapsack-problem

```
def knapSack(cap, wt, val, n, stuff):
   # initial conditions
    items_to_pack=[]
    if n == 0 or cap == 0 :
      return 0
   # If weight is higher than capacity then it is not included
    if (wt[n-1] > cap):
      return knapSack(cap, wt, val, n-1, stuff)
   # return either nth item being included or not
    else:
        items_to_pack.append(stuff[n-1])
        return  max(val[n-1] + knapSack(cap-wt[n-1], wt, val, n-1, stuff),
         knapSack(cap, wt, val, n-1, stuff))
        return print(items_to_pack)
# To test above function
items = (
    ("Item 1", 9, 20), ("Item 2", 1, 1), ("Item 3", 5, 11), ("Item 4", 4, 10)
    )
cap = 10
val=[]
wt=[]
thing=[]
for i in range(len(items)):
    val.append(items[i][2])
for i in range(len(items)):
    wt.append(items[i][1])
for i in range(len(items)):
    thing.append(items[i][0])
n = len(val)
print ('items_topack:', knapSack(cap, wt, val, n, thing))
```

Working a knapsack function, that will output max value and the items packed in the bag.
First Problem is fixed, but now it is only output the max value, and not providing the items packed in the bag.

Any advice?

Comment: You're missing an argument if you count them. `knapsack` takes five arguments, but `knapSack(cap-wt[n-1], wt, val, n-1)` is only passing four.

Comment: So fixed that but it is only putting the max value, on the items packed in the bag?

Comment: What do you expect `return print(items_to_pack)` to do, exactly?

Comment: I expect "items_to_pack.append(stuff[n-1])" to add the item being used to the list item_to_pack and then I am trying to use "return print(items_to_pack" to print the list of items packed